# SQL Server : Add max(column_value)+1 when NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables namely Test2 and Test3.

I have 10 records in the `Test2` table. And no records in the `Test3` table.

In the table Test2 i have some null values in the column `ColumnID`.

I want to insert records into table `Test3` by selecting records from table `Test2` **AND** when there is null
value i just want to add it with max of column `ColumnID` plus 1.

**Table**: Test2

```
Create table Test2
(
  ColumnID int
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO Test2 values(1);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(2);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(3);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(5);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(8);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(null);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(null);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(null);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(null);
INSERT INTO Test2 values(null);
```

**Expected Result**:

Table : Test3

```
ColumnID
----------------
1
2
3
5
8
9  --Increament by 1 to max of id
10 --increment by 1 to max of id  
11
12
13
```

## Try : 1

```
INSERT INTO Test3
SELECT Case WHEN ColumnID IS NOT NULL then ColumnID  else max(ColumnID)+1 end as Column_ID
from Test2
group by ColumnID;
```

## Try : 2

```
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @i int = 1
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM Test2;

WHILE (@i <= @count)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test3 
    SELECT Case WHEN ColumnID IS NOT NULL then ColumnID  else max(ColumnID)+1 end as Column_ID
    from Test2
    group by ColumnID;
    set @i = @i + 1;
END
GO
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Your question need to add an `ORDER` logic when you select record from **Test2** to add to **Test3**. If you add with order `1, null, 3, null, 5`, the result will differ from `null, null, 1, 3, 5` .

Comment: @SankarRaj, 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Test3
SELECT COALESCE(ColumnID, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By ColumnID 
                                   ORDER BY ColumnID) +  
                MAX(ColumnID) OVER ()) 
FROM Test2
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GVWQ87371)